# curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, array(&$this,'readHeader')) not working

Tags: php, curl, joomla, header

I have this wrapper to load a symfony project from within Joomla

```
class NZGBCComponentHelper {
    function requestAndFollow($path = '') {
        $c = 0;$first = 1;$httpcode = 0;
        $uri = JRequest::getVar('uri');
        while ($c <= 4 && ($first || $httpcode == 302)){
            $first = 0;
            $finalSfUrl = NZGBCComponentHelper::buildRequestUri($uri, $path);

            $ch = curl_init($finalSfUrl);

            if(JRequest::getMethod() == 'POST' && $httpcode != 302){
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                $postThrough = array_merge(JRequest::get($_POST),array('_csrf_token' => $_POST['_csrf_token']));
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postThrough));
            }

            // Get sf content
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, JURI::getInstance()->root().$path);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, 'readHeader');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'symfony='.$_COOKIE['symfony']);

            $return = curl_exec($ch);
            $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);


            if (!$return){
                $error = curl_error($ch);
            }

            if($this->headers['Set-Cookie']){
                JResponse::setHeader('Set-Cookie', $mainframe->sym_headers['Set-Cookie']);
            }
            if ($httpcode >= 400){
                $return = "There was an <!--$finalSfUrl-->  error ";
                mail ('jd@automatem.co.nz', 'symfony wrapper error',
                $finalSfUrl."\r\n".
                $httpcode."\r\n".
                $return
                );

            }else if ($httpcode == 302){
                $query = parse_url(trim($mainframe->sym_headers['Location']), PHP_URL_QUERY);
                parse_str($query);
                parse_str($uri);
                if ($outside == 'true'){
                    JApplication::redirect(trim(urldecode($uri)));
                }
            }
            curl_close($ch);
            $c++;
        }
        return $return;

    }
    }

    if (!function_exists('readHeader')){
    function readHeader($ch, $header){

        $mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication();
        if($pos = strpos($header, ':')){
            $mainframe->sym_headers[substr($header, 0, $pos)] = substr(strstr($header, ':'), 1);
        }

        return strlen($header);
    }
}
```

requestAndFollow is statically called. How can I refer to readHeader() instead of putting it into the global function space. I tried:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, array(&$this,'readHeader'));//didn't expect this to work - no $this when statically called


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, array('NZGBCComponentHelper','readHeader'));


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, array(self,'readHeader'));
```

Comment: how about `NZGBCComponentHelper::readHeader` ??

Comment: edit your title to **Using wrapper to load a symphony project whitin Joomla ?** you will get faster respond

Comment: @Syncmax: I got a working wrapper based on what was out there. The problem is specific to calling this function statically. I got a workaround as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears this works fine on

- libcurl 7.19.7, Ubuntu 10.10, PHP 5.3.2

but not on

- libcurl 7.18.2 on Debian Lenny, PHP 5.2.6

A working workaround on both versions is to put the header function in the global space

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, 'readHeader');
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, array($this,'readHeader'));
```

Comment: `$this` doesn't exist in static calls.

Answer (score 0):

are u getting ant error like curl_init() not defined?

Enable display error and see if you can get this message.

If you get this message then the cause that CURL is not installed properly.

Comment: Hey I too am having the same issue. The readHeader method is not called. I have a class wherein I am calling the curl_exec() method and the method readHeader is defined globally. But the error is still persistent.

Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

No need to pollute global namespace:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, 'NZGBCComponentHelper::readHeader');
```