# How to curl and display image where file type is unknown from url

Tags: php, html, image, curl

**Background**

- I am building an image search for oscobo, a privacy search engine.
- We use a Bing URL to fetch thumbnails to display to the user on the image search results page. For example: https://oscobo.com/image.php?q=london.
- We do not want to connect the client to Bing directly (as in the above example) but intend to use a reverse proxy script that uses cURL to fetch the image and then send it back to the browser.
- The script works well when we know what the file type is (e.g. jpg) and we can pick the correct content-type for the Header accordingly before we echo the image back to the browser.
- The problem we have is that the URL to Bing does not contain the filetype, it looks along the lines of http://tse3.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.M1a65dd11fb2b159f4fe44eba7dcfa0a6H0&pid=15.1&H=90&W=160

**Question**

How can we modify this script to work with the URL that does not display the file type?

Any ideas or input much appreciated.

**The PHP on the page**

```
$html = '';
$images = $results->bossresponse->images->results;
foreach ($images as $image) {
                    $theurl = "{$image->thumbnailurl}";
                    $theurl = base64_encode($theurl);
                    $reverseurl = "reverseproxy.php?url=$theurl";
                    $html .= "<a href=\"{$image->clickurl}\"> <img class=border src=\"$reverseurl\" height=\"140px\"></a>";
                    }
echo $html;
```

**The reverse script reverseproxy.php**

```
<?php
$file = base64_decode(@$_GET['url']);
$aFile = end(explode('.' , $file));
if($aFile == 'jpg' or $aFile == 'jpeg'){
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
}elseif($aFile == 'png'){
header('Content-Type: image/png');
}elseif($aFile == 'gif'){
header('Content-Type: image/gif');
}else{
die('not supported');
}

if($file != ''){
        $cache_expire = 60*60*24*365;
        header("Pragma: public");
        header("Cache-Control: maxage=". $cache_expire);
        header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time() +         $cache_expire).' GMT');

//The cURL stuff...
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "$file");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
$picture = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
//Display the image in the browser

echo $picture;

    }
    exit;      

    ?>
```

Comment: Have you looked at CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION to read the HTTP header as the file is downloaded? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6482068/curl-setoptch-curlopt-headerfunction-arraythis-readheader-not-working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick test in the console shows that the image type information can be obtained from the response header: `curl -D headers.txt http://tse3.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.M1a65dd11fb2b159f4fe44eba7dcfa0a6H0&pid=15.1&H=90&W=160` 
So you could consider the HTTP response header. This answer shows how it can be done with cURL in PHP: [Can PHP cURL retrieve response headers AND body in a single request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183178/php-curl-retrieving-response-headers-and-body-in-a-single-request)

Hope this helps, good luck!